# SQL Server Configuration Manager: "The specified file is read only"

Tags: sql-server, windows, ip-address

After installing SQL Server Express 2012 on my Windows 7 machine, when saving changes in `SQL Server Configuration Manager` for TCP/IP protocol, It errors with

> The specified file is read only. [0x80071779]

**Update:** The issue seemed to resolve itself.

Comment: A couple of questions to help get an answer for you. Do you have admin rights to that server? Is the service you are trying to change running with domain creds?

Comment: Yes and yes. Weirdly, the issue has resolved itself. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Same problem on a brand new install of SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2019. Had to go with directly editing the registry.

Answer (score 20):

I have the same issue with installing sql 2012 Developer on W7 x64 Pro.

I have solved this huge issue by modify manually the Registry database in :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp]
```

Comment: After modifying in the registry, further attempts to save were allowed